# Router` no longer defaults the history prop to hash history

Tags: reactjs, react-router, ecmascript-5

Using React-Router in ES5, I have the below code

```
var React = require('react');
var Render = require('react-dom').render;
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var hashHistory = Router.hashHistory;
var browserHistory = Router.browserHistory;

var About = require('./components/about/aboutPage');

var routes = (
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" handler={App}>
            <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
        </Route>
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

This is rendered in {main.j} as

```
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var routes = require('./routes');

ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

However, in the console, am getting this warning and nothing loads up:

```
bundle.js:1845 Warning: [react-router] `Router` no longer defaults the history prop to hash history. Please use the `hashHistory` singleton instead
```

I have clearly passed {hashHistory} in the code above, but still it keeps on complaining.

Any hints on what could be going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the reason - It was an issue with my rendering code

```
ReactDOM.render(<Router>{routes}</Router>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

as {routes} already contained {}, there was no need to specify it again whilst rendering. Because of this, ofcourse, {history} prop was missing in the render code. So, I just changed the render code to:

```
ReactDOM.render(routes, document.getElementById('app'));
```

and it works perfectly fine!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

No you didn't.You have just defined it and not used it. You have to pass `history={hashHistory}` in the router Tag.

```
var React = require('react');
var Render = require('react-dom').render;
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;
var hashHistory = Router.hashHistory;
var browserHistory = Router.browserHistory;

var About = require('./components/about/aboutPage');

var routes = (
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" handler={App}>
            <Route path="about" handler={About}/>
        </Route>
  </Router>
);

module.exports = routes;
```

> P.S. react-router 2.8.0 requires react v15.3.0 and above. Visit the
> following link.

https://www.versioneye.com/nodejs/react-router/2.8.0

If you dont have this, I would suggest you use react-router v2.0.0 or update you react to the required version.

Comment: I did that, but still the warning persists. Am going through the react-router code itself now and am seeing that it calls [function isDeprecatedHistory(history) {
  return !history || !history.__v2_compatible__
}] which seems to be returning true causing the warning to be generated. Not sure why that's returning true as history is non-null and is V2 Compatible

Comment: which version of react-router are you using

Comment: am currently using 2.8.0

Comment: Am using the following versions already: "react": "^15.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.3.1",
    "react-router": "^2.8.0",

Comment: now I can just suggest you to try to use a different version of react-router and see if it works

Comment: solved this, posted the answer. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Right I also did not notice it. But yeah you need to include hashhistory too as I mentioned